construct homotopy between two refinement maps, exercise 10.5 of Bott, Tu
The question is the exercise 10.5, page 111, hidden in a lemma of Bott, Tu, Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology.
The background is below:
Lemma 10.4.2. Given $u = \{U_{\alpha}\}$ an open cover and $b = \{V_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in J}$ a refinement, if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two refinement maps: $J \rightarrow I$, then there is a homotopy operator between $\phi^*$ and $\psi^*$.
Proof. Define $K: C^q(u, F) \rightarrow C^{q-1}(b, F)$ by
$(K\omega)V_{\beta_0, ..., \beta_{q-1}} = \sum(-1)^i\omega(U_{\phi(\beta_0), ..., \phi(\beta_i)\psi(\beta_i)...\psi(\beta_{q-1})})$.
Here $C^q(u, F)$ is Cech cohomology of a presheaf $F$.
then we use the following exercise to complete the proof.
Exercise 10.5. Show that $\psi^* - \phi^* = \delta K + K\delta$. Here $\delta: C^p(u, F) \rightarrow C^{p+1}(u, F)$.
How to prove exercise 10.5.

It is a "straightforward" calculation. Have you tried it? Where do you get stuck?
